# getActionBar() == null When it Shouldn't

Tags: android, android-actionbar, actionbarsherlock, android-4.0-ice-cream-sandwich, robolectric

I feel like I must be missing something crazy. I am converting my code written to work with ABS (and it did work), and switching it to use the native ActionBar. I set the min SDK to 14 and switched things out for the framework versions, now I can't get the `ActionBar` to exist.

My `Activity`:

```
public class HomeActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(@CheckForNull Bundle icicle) {
        super.onCreate(icicle);
        getWindow().requestFeature(Window.FEATURE_ACTION_BAR);
    }
}
```

My AndroidManifest:

```
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="14" android:targetSdkVersion="17"/>
...
<activity android:launchMode="singleTop" android:name=".ui.HomeActivity" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Holo">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
    </intent-filter>
    <meta-data android:name="target device" android:value="universal"/>
</activity>
```

My Robolectric Test:

```
@RunWith(RobolectricTestRunner.class)
public class HomeActivityTest {

    @Test
    public void testActionBarDisplay() {
        // Given
        final HomeActivity activity_under_testing = new HomeActivity();

        // When
        activity_under_testing.onCreate(null);

        // Then
        assertThat(activity_under_testing.getActionBar())
        .hasDisplayOptions(ActionBar.DISPLAY_SHOW_HOME
                           |ActionBar.DISPLAY_SHOW_TITLE
                           |ActionBar.DISPLAY_USE_LOGO);
    }
}
```

I'm using FEST-Android for the `assertThat` (couldn't possibly be the issue).

The issue:

> Tests run: 1, Failures: 1, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 7.563 sec <<< FAILURE!
>   testActionBarDisplay(com.imminentmeals.android.base.ui.HomeActivityTest)  Time elapsed: 6.588 sec  <<< FAILURE!
>   java.lang.AssertionError: expecting actual not to be null
>       at com.imminentmeals.android.base.ui.HomeActivityTest.testActionBarDisplay(HomeActivityTest.java:28)

I should add that I'm using **Robolectric 2.0 Alpha 2**. I skipped the test, and packaged my apk, and the `ActionBar` seems to work fine, so I'm feeling like this must be a Robolectric issue? But I thought it should work fine with native Android since it was running native Android code.

Answer (score 4):

This question is rather old but I will post my solution in case someone faces the same problem.

I was facing the same problem as Dandre, where I was using Robolectric 2.3, minSDK 16, and using the native ActonBar and yet **getActionBar()** kept returnign null. The solution was to ensure my style was referring to a theme which explicitly mentions ActionBar. In my case,I was using **Theme.Light**. By changing the theme to **Theme.Holo.Light.DarkActionBar**, I got it to work. I believe Dandre had the same issue, given that his theme was **Theme.Holo**.

I find it weird that the theme was the cause of the problem, given that it does not affect my app. Maybe someone can explain why?

Comment: Thanks for sharing, I believe I stripped out the specifics of my Theme name, but any theme that results in a visible ActionBar when run should not return `null` in Robolectric world.

Comment: That's what I thought so too, since my app had a visible action bar even with the Theme.Light. I never thought it would be the cause of my problem

Comment: I had a similar problem and looked at my theme many times while trying to debug and it seemed right to me. After reading this answer, I looked at my theme carefully and realised I'd being seeing what I thought should be there and not what was actually there. *sigh* so many wasted hours.

Comment: I had to make this change to `android:theme` on my `<application>`. Setting it on the `<activity>` was not sufficient.

Answer (score 1):

if you use ActionBarDrawerToggle 
put getActionBar() inside of onDrawerOpened(View drawerView){}
`public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {
                title =  getActionBar().getTitle();
                getActionBar().setTitle("Open Drawer");
  }`

Answer (score 1):

> Extend ActionBarActivity in place of FragmentActivity.

- ActionBarActivity internally extends FragmentActivity, so no need to worry.
- Use android.support.v7 type ActionBar Activity.

  ```
  import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
  ```

> Use getSupportActionBar() in place of getActionBar()

- Check in your Manifest file, if NoTitleBar theme is used then remove that line

> android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar"    // remove this line

- If still problem is not resolved then use FEATURE_ACTION_BAR above the setContentView() method.

> requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_ACTION_BAR);

Comment: Hmm, this probably works, but it's soo old now that I don't have any of the old code.

Answer (score 0):

In your Manifest you should make the theme `Theme.Sherlock` instead of `Theme.Holo`.

You need to extend `SherlockActivity` or `SherlockFragmentActivity`.

To return the `ActionBar` call `getSupportActionBar` when you're using ABS.

Also, you don't need to call `Window.FEATURE_ACTION_BAR`. Using the Holo theme is enough.

**From the ActionBarSherlock docs**

> Action Bar API
>
> When creating an activity to use the action bar on all versions of
>   Android, you must declare your activity to extend any of the activity
>   classes that start with 'Sherlock' (e.g., SherlockActivity,
>   SherlockFragmentActivity). Interaction with the action bar is handled
>   by calling getSupportActionBar() (instead of getActionBar()).

[You can read the docs here](http://actionbarsherlock.com/usage.html)

[You can read more about styling ABS here](http://actionbarsherlock.com/theming.html)

Comment: Check my question again, I'm *no* longer using ABS, I switched to the framework, my minSDK is 14. Also the Window.FEATURE_ACTION_BAR doesn't hurt anything, and is there because it is stated in previous answers to similar questions, although I realize it should not be necessary. I've been trying most things I can find.

Comment: Ah, my bad. I misunderstood and thought you were wanting to switch to ABS.

Comment: Got it, I rephrased it, so that shouldn't happen again